# .find() function in python isn't working

Tags: string, python-2.7, substring

I've just written this to test out the .find() function in python 2.7 but it doesn't seem to work. My syntax looks right but i cant figure out why it's not working.

```
s=raw_input('Please state two facts about yourself')

if s.find('24' and 'England'):
    print 'are you Jack Wilshere?'
else:
    print 'are you Thierry Henry?'
```

Comment: `'24' and 'England'` expression would give you a boolean == False and this is what it is going to search for.

Comment: So how would i get this to search for these two words and print something depending if those words are in there?

Answer (score 3):

Your boolean and use of `.find()` are both wrong.

First, if you `and` together `'24' and 'England'` you just get `'England'`:

```
>>> '24' and 'England'
'England'
```

That is because both strings are `True` in a Python sense so the right most is the result from `and`. So when you use `s.find('24' and 'England')` you are only searching for `'England'`

The `.find()` returns the index of the substring -- `-1` if not found which is also `True` in a Python sense:

```
>>> bool(-1)
True
```

And `.find()` could return the index `0` for a string that starts with the target string yet, in a boolean sense, `0` is `False`. So in this case you would incorrectly think that string was not found.

The correct operator to test for presence or membership testing in Python is [in](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
>>> s='I am 24 and live in England'
>>> '24' in s and 'England' in s
True
```

You can write your `if` statement that way, or more idiomatically, to test more than one condition, use `all` (for `and`) or `any` (for `or`) with `in`:

```
>>> all(e in s for e in ('24','England'))
True
>>> any(e in s for e in ('France','England'))
True
>>> all(e in s for e in ('France','England'))
False
```

Then you can seamlessly add conditions in the future rather than change your code.

Answer (score 0):

Find does not return a boolean, it returns the starting index of the found value. If the value can't be found, it returns -1.

```
s=raw_input('Please state two facts about yourself')

if s.find('24') >=0 and s.find ('England') >= 0:
    print 'are you Jack Wilshere?'
else:
    print 'are you Thierry Henry?'
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `s.count()` 
or `s.find() != -1:` on each: England and 24

```
if s.find('24' and 'England'):  # it's a number which is always true hence your code is failing
```

Comment: seriously @PrestonM, a down vote? can you tell me why?

Comment: Try `print('24' and 'England')`. Also, you can't know which user downvoted you. No, it wasn't me either.

Comment: on each... means s.find('24') and s.find('England'). Would say on both if wanted to use them together

Comment: You need to edit your answer and make it more clear. Especially the point i mentioned. What `'24' and 'England'` does _exactly_, and how _exactly_ he should do it instead.